# Help with finding an analytic function on a given domain

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm a bit puzzled by this one.

The domain $X = S(0,1)\cup S(3,1)$ (where $S(\alpha, \rho)$ is a circular area with it's center at $\alpha$ and radius $\rho$). So the domain is basically two circles with radius 1 and centers at 0 and 3.

I'm supposed to find analytic function $f$ defined on $X$ where the imaginary part of $f$ is a constant but $f$ is not constant.

Where do I start?

Comment: The key is that the domain is not a domain ;) [the latter occurrence of the word "domain" was in the sense of "connected open set"]

Answer (score 0):

Hint: a function with constant imaginary part is constant **on a connected domain**.  Yours is not connected.

Answer (score 0):

You can take $f\equiv 0$ on one disk and $f\equiv 1$ on the other. Then $\operatorname{Im}f\equiv 0$ everywhere, but $f$ isn't constant.

Comment: but is $f$ analytic then?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is certainly constant (so, differentiable) on an open disk about each point of its domain, right? Remember, analyticity is a local property.